# Concatenate values in same object's property inside reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an *array* of *objects* like this:

```
let array = [{
    "Age": 20,
    "Name": "Kevin"
}, {
    "Age": 15,
    "Name": "Alfred"
}, {
    "Age": 30,
    "Name": "Joe"
}];
```

I want to get an object like this:

```
{
    "Age": '20, 15, 30',
    "Name": 'Kevin, Alfred, Joe'
}
```

If I do:

```
let r = array.reduce(function(pV, cV) {
    Object.keys(cV).map(function(key){
        pV[key] = (pV[key] || []).concat(cV[key]);
    });
    return pV;
},{});

console.log(r); // { "Age": [20, 15, 30], "Name": ['Kevin', 'Alfred', 'Joe'] }
```

Or if I do:

```
let r = array.reduce(function(pV, cV) {
    Object.keys(cV).map(function(key){
        pV[key] = (pV[key] || '') + ', ' + cV[key];
    });
    return pV;
},{});

console.log(r); // { "Age": ', 20, 15, 30', "Name": ', Kevin, Alfred, Joe' }
```

I'm a little bit lost. Some ideas on how to get what I need?

Comment: What do you want to get as the output on an empty array?

Comment: The object of arrays looks good already, now you just have to `r.Age = r.Age.join(", ")` and the same for the names.

Comment: @Bergi It is possible to use the `join(", ")` inside the `reduce` ???

Comment: Not really, no, you want to do it afterwards not in every step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close with your second appraoch, you just have to make sure that the initial `,` does not appear, which is quite easy with a ternary:

```
let r = array.reduce(function(pV, cV) {
  Object.keys(cV).map(function(key){
      pV[key] = (pV[key] ? (pV[key] + ", ") :  '') + cV[key];
  });
  return pV;
},{});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me a lot !

Comment: @robe007 glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code using `.reduce()` and `Object.keys`

```js
let array = [{
    "Age": 20,
    "Name": "Kevin"
}, {
    "Age": 15,
    "Name": "Alfred"
}, {
    "Age": 30,
    "Name": "Joe"
}];

let result = array.reduce((current,result) => {
 Object.keys(current).forEach(key => {
  if(!result[key]){
   result[key] = current[key];
  } else {
   result[key]+= ", " + current[key];
  }
 })
 return result;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `reduce` like that, which is just a glorified loop:

```
let r = {};
for (const cV of array) {
    for (const key in cV) {
        r[key] = (r[key] || []).concat(cV[key]);
    }
}
```

For a functional approach, where the `map` would be actually useful, I'd nest the iterations the other way round:

```
let r = {};
for (const key of ["Age", "Name"]) { // or Object.keys(array[0])
    r[key] = array.map(function(cV){
        return cV[key];
    }).join(", ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting one !

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way as well.

```
 array.reduce((a,n)=>{
 a.Age =  a.Age+','+n.Age;
a.Name = a.Name+','+n.Name;
return a;
});
```

Warning!! this approach with modify actual array of object. 
If that is not intended then you can clone object first and then do reduce.

I did `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` to clone array you can use your own ways to deep clone it.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)).reduce((a,n)=>{
 a.Age =  a.Age+', '+n.Age;
a.Name = a.Name+', '+n.Name;
return a;
})
```

Comment: Careful, this will change the original array.

Comment: yes it will. in that case we can clone array before we do this operation.

Comment: thanks @MarkMeyer i just updated according to your comments. upvote!!  for your suggestion.

Comment: @ManojYadav Thanks for your answer, but I prefer to not use _literally notations_ with objects, that's why I'm using `Object.keys`.